# Node.js Header Deprecation Error Message in Mac 10.13 VSC

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Good afternoon.

I've been fighting with Visual Studio Code for about a week now with an XMPie support rep and neither of us can figure out how to resolve this issue. My experience with React and Node.js is still beginner level as well, so if there is anything I'm obviously missing please let me know.

After launching a localhost for testing from VSC, when I attempt to work on a site skin in React, I get a "(node:77089) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated" everytime I save the change. As such, the localhost does not update in the browser.

The tech was able to finally replicate my issue by first installing node.js v14 and then downgrading to v12 which is the version that is approved.

I've done the following steps to try and fix the issue.
Uninstalled node and npm from the terminal

Verified/Deleted node related files/directories at:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
/usr/local/include/node
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/share/doc/node
/usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
/usr/local/systemtap/tapset/node.stp

Restarted, then reinstalled v12 of node.

However, the deprecated issue still remains and neither of us can figure out why that is. New user accounts exhibit this same behavior as well. Short of wiping and reinstalling the OS, I'm hoping to find out what we're missing to fix this issue. Thanks for your time and any assistance you can provide.